# using NLTK methods such as tokenize on annotated text

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, tokenize

Say I have a corpus of annotated text where a sentence looks something like:

```
txt = 'red foxes <emotion>scare</emption> me.'
```

is it possible to tokenize this using word_tokenize in such as way that we get:

```
['red', 'foxes', '<emotion>scare<emotion>', 'me', '.']
```

We could use an alternative annotation scheme say:

```
txt = 'red foxes scare\_EMOTION me'
```

Is it possible to do this with NLTK -- currently I'm parsing out the annotations and then tracking them out of band and it is very cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the desired result you don't need `nltk`.

Just run `txt.split()`

If you insist on using `nltk`, check out the different [tokenizers](http://text-processing.com/demo/tokenize/).

`PunktWordTokenizer` and `WhitespaceTokenizer` fit.

Comment: true, but the idea is when I want to do POS, I can simply pass in my annotated text and have NLTK pretend that the annotations don't exist.